# How can i add block to existing layout in catalog_category_view.xml?

Tags: magento2, module, layout, magento-2.2.5, development

I want change layout of catalaog_category_view.xml but i can't. I override block category.products and it's work but how can i add my own block to existing category.products block? Because i want add my own element above of category.products element. I was trying add block and move element, add to referenceContainer content and move before category.products and nothing happened. Still the same page exists. Can you help me how can i add block inside category.products or above category.products.

```
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View" name="category.products" template="Magento_Catalog::category/products.phtml">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct" name="category.products.list" as="product_list" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list.phtml">
                <container name="category.product.list.additional" as="additional" />
                <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\RendererList" name="category.product.type.details.renderers" as="details.renderers">
                    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="category.product.type.details.renderers.default" as="default"/>
                </block>
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\Container" name="category.product.addto" as="addto">
                    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\AddTo\Compare"
                           name="category.product.addto.compare" as="compare"
                           template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/addto/compare.phtml"/>
                </block>
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/toolbar.phtml">
                    <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
                </block>
                <action method="setToolbarBlockName">
                    <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">product_list_toolbar</argument>
                </action>
            </block>
        </block>
```

This is block category.products from Magento_Catalog. I want add my block above this one:

```
 <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View" name="category.products" template="Magento_Catalog::category/products.phtml">
```

Or:

```
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View" name="category.products" template="Magento_Catalog::category/products.phtml"><!-- Before category.products.list -->
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct" name="category.products.list" as="product_list" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list.phtml">
```

Anyone can help me? I will be really grateful!

Comment: Have you tried with this? <move element="yourblock" destination="content" before="category.products" />

Comment: `<referenceBlock name="category.products">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">MGS_Landing::category/products.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>` - This code override standard category.products. I'm beginner developer of magento2. Where i must create additional block which will show above category.products? Inside referenceBlock or somewhere else?

Comment: Do you want to replace default magento's layout of category.products block or want to create a new block before category.products block?

Comment: I solved this problem with your tips :) `<block class="ModuleOwn\Landing\Block\Landing" name="landingown" template="ModuleOwn::category/landing/grid.phtml"/>
        <referenceBlock name="category.products">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">ModuleOwn::category/products1.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
        <move element="landingown" destination="content" before="category.products" />`

Comment: Great :) I'm posting my answer, may be it may helpful to anyone else.

Comment: @DharaBhatti but i've got one more question. How can i change this own block in code? I want change this block depends of value checked in magento2 admin panel. `<block class="ModuleOwn\Landing\Block\Landing" name="landingown" template="ModuleOwn::category/landing/grid.phtml"/>` this block i want change dynamic? Is any way to change template for existing block?

Comment: Yes, you can use "ifconfig" attribute. Search for that in google, you will get more idea.

Comment: But i've got value from DB. So how can i change template for this block?

Comment: Which value you got from DB? Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Someone choose 1 of 3 style in adminhtml. After that category page depends of chosen value show one of three templates. For example i've chosen "option1" and i want for "option1" template for  block landingown set template option1.phtml, but for option2 template option2.phtml.

Comment: I know it's possible using `$this->getLayout()->createBlock("block")->setTemplate("template")->toHtml()` but for me it's problematically because when i click filter the block with landing page duplicate each time when i click filter :(

Comment: For that you should create new question.

Comment: Ok, thanks for help dude :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `<move>` element in following way:

```
<move element="yourblock" destination="content" before="category.products" />
```

Hope may helpful to anyone.